# How do I set PredictionMode.SSL in antlr4 JavaScript runtime

Tags: javascript, antlr4

I'm using antlr4 JavaScript runtime in a project to parse a custom boolean query language. I've noticed that some more complicated queries are fairly slow to parse and I looked around for a solution.

The Java documentation is quite good, and usually the JavaScript runtime does pretty much everything that the Java does, so I found a solution that looks like a good option in this github issue: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/192

It suggests a two-stage parsing strategy, first setting the error strategy to `BailErrorStrategy` and using `PredictionMode.SLL`, falling back to `DefaultErrorStrategy` and `PredictionMode.LL` in case of an error.

My question is this: how do I set the PredictionMode using the JavaScript runtime? I'm using antlr4 version 4.6.0 from npm, and the ParserATNSimulater doesn't seem to have a `setPredictionMode` method like the Java documentation suggests. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look in the source code shows there is a public property in ParserATNSimulator (`this.predictionMode`, line 272). That should do it, right?

Comment: Thanks, this should do the trick. If not, antlr4ts seems to have the method.

Comment: I recommend antlr4ts anyway (been using it since first alpha). Works very well for me and it's good for writing node modules as well.